# what is the definition of an interpretation of first order theory $T$ ? what is a model for $T$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

what is the definition of an  interpretation of  first order theory $T$ ? what is a model for $T$ ?

can you give me the definition supported with some simple examples ?

---

i read the definition in first order mathematical logic by angelo margaris , 1990 ed , dover publications , in page 35

but the definition made no sense for me..

thanx

Comment: A very good rule: never rely on just one textbook. Different books have different virtues, and what you find to be done too briskly in one book will probably be done in a slightly different way in another book. So always have a supplementary text or two to refer to when working through your set text. For some suggestions see http://logicmatters.net/students/tyl/

Comment: If you're having trouble with a definition, you should give the definition in question and explain exactly what parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry on Wikipedia: [First-order Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) helps to disambiguate the terms, and sort of gives examples.

See especially, under the heading "Semantics":

- "First order structure"

  > "The most common way of *specifying an interpretation* (especially in mathematics) is to specify a structure (also called *a model*; see below). *The **structure [model]** consists of a nonempty set D that forms the domain of discourse and **an interpretation I** of the non-logical terms of the signature. This interpretation is itself a function*..."
- "Satisfiability",
- the sub-section "first-order theories and models",

  - "*A first-order structure that satisfies all sentences in a given theory is said to be a model of the theory*."

---

One great resource, as you embark on your study of Enderton (and perhaps good to read before digging deeply into Enderton) is Paul Teller's [**Logic Primer**](http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/pdf/). (It's free to download, and importantly, discusses interpretations and models extensively, as it does tautological implication, wff, and First Order Logic in general.)

Answer (score 4):

Consider for example the theory of partial ordered groups:

In their language there is a binary operation symbol, $\cdot$ (the multiplication), a constant symbol $1$ (the unit), a unary operation symbol ${()}^{-1}$, and a binary relation symbol $\le$. (The equality symbol is usually assumed to be also present, by default.) An axiom system for it is the $6$ element set $T$ of the following formulas ($T$ itself is also called the *theory*):

1. $\forall x\forall y\forall z \ ((x\cdot y)\cdot z=x\cdot(y\cdot z))$
2. $\forall x\ (1\cdot x=x)$
3. $\forall x\ (x^{-1}\cdot x=1)$
4. $\forall x\ (x\le x)$
5. $\forall x\forall y\forall z\ ((x\le y\,\land\, y\le z )\implies x\le z)$
6. $\forall x\forall y\forall z\ (x\le y \implies (x\cdot z\le y\cdot z\ \land\ z\cdot x\le z\cdot y) )$

A model of $T$ is a realization of the operation and relation symbols on a base set such that they satisfy the axioms. So, first we have to consider a *model* $\mathfrak M$ for the given first order language: it is thus far nothing else than a set $M$, equipped with a binary ($\mu:M\times M\to M$), a unary ($\sigma:M\to M$) and a constant ($c\in M$) operation, and a binary relation $(L\subseteq M\times M)$.

This $\mathfrak M$ is said to be a model for $T$, if all elemets of $T$ is satisfied on $\mathfrak M$ when interpreting the symbols accordingly, with respect to all evaluations of the variables (whenever the variable $x$ is evaluated in $M$,  $x\cdot y$ is evaluated as $\mu(x,y)$, $x^{-1}$ as $\sigma(x)$, $1$ as $c$, and $x\le y$ as $(x,y)\in L$).